# Adding value from one pandas dataframe to another dataframe by matching a variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matching

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe  `df` with 2 columns

```
           c1            c2
    0      v1            b1
    1      v2            b2
    2      v3            b3
    3      v4            b4
    4      v5            b5
```

A second dataframe, `df2` contains c1, c2 and a few other columns.

```
   c1 c2 c3  c4
0  "" b5 500 3
1  "" b2 420 7
2  "" b1 380 5
3  "" b2 470 9
4  "" b3 290 2
```

My goal is to replace the empty values for c1 in df2, with those in df, corresponding to the values in c2, so the first five values for c1 in df2, should be v5,v2,v1,v2 and v3 respectively. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way you can do is to use the merge of pandas based on similar column.

`df2.drop('c1', axis=1, inplace=True)`

`main_df = pd.merge(df2, df, on="c2", how="left")`

`df2['c1'] = main_df['c1']`

`df2.columns = ['c1','c2','c3','c4']`

Comment: This gives me NaNs for c1

Comment: Then you can drop the C1 column of df2. See the updated code. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# remove the c1 column from df2
df2.drop("c1", axis=1, inplace=True)
# merge the 2 dataframes and get the c1 values corresponding to c2
newdf = df.merge(df2, on="c2")
```

If you actually have missing values in the column (i.e. NAs and some rows where values are present, the solution will be different)

Comment: No, this gives an empty data frame as a result. My goal is not to merge dataframes, it's to replace missing values in c1 in df2, with those in df1, corresponding to c2

Comment: try running this first :  df2.drop("c1", axis=0, inplace=True). Then run the other code.

Comment: got this error KeyError: "['c1'] not found in axis"

Comment: sorry, axis should be 1

Comment: One small problem with this approach, after merging the dataframe is sorted by c2. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: Try something like this : new df = df.sort_index(ascending=False)  which should sort by the index number rather than a specific column

Comment: Is there way to do this without creating a new dataframe at all? Just replacing the empty values in df2

Comment: Sure. Just reassign to df2 instead of newdf i.e. df2 = df.merge(df2, on="c2")